# jquery-ui datepicker onchange

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to correct all datepicker's values on client side.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    onClose: function(date) {
        // calculate proper date string
        $(this).val(properDate);
        $(this).trigger('blur');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work if I switch tab in browser. Change event generates, but onClose method is not called.

I can subscribe to change event manualy using dom selector:

```
$(".datepicker").change(function() {...});
```

But I don't like it because I have dynamicaly added elements. I want to add change event handler to element in datepicker's constructor.

What can you advise me?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MathiasBecher, if user input date from keyboard, he can incorrectly input date. I wan't to check it on client side.

Comment: You can add a validation with regex like `/^([0-9]{2})(\.[0-9]{2})(\.[0-9]{4})$/`.

Comment: @JuanSedano, question is not "How to check date". Question is "How to bind function to change event of all datepickers". And your regex is incorrect: 99.99.2015.

Comment: I see in the comments "if user input date from keyboard, he can incorrectly input date. I wan't to check it on client side", the regex is only an example that you can validate it with regex, i know if not complete...

Comment: @JuanSedano, I already have function to validate, but I don't know how to make it handle **all** change events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/psoubh9k/1/

I realized datechooser, that bind change event to my function and apply datepicker to element.

```
var methods = {
    init : function(options) {
        $(this).change(validate);
        options = $.extend(true, options, {
            onClose: validate,
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
        });
        return $(this).datepicker(options);
    }
};
```